# Excel, extra brackets change value of formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, brackets

I am adding the values of several cells from two sheets in excel.

I am using the formulas below to calculate this.

My question is why to two formulas aren't giving the same result? As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the 2nd formula has an extra bracket, which shouldn't change anything?

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Ark1'!F15:F75;'Ark1'!E15:E75;{"adgangsareal bolig";"fællesrum bolig"}))+SUM(SUMIFS('Ark2'!F11:F126;'Ark2'!E11:E126;"bolig"))

=SUM((SUMIFS('Ark1'!F15:F75;'Ark1'!E15:E75;{"adgangsareal bolig";"fællesrum bolig"}))+SUM(SUMIFS('Ark2'!F11:F126;'Ark2'!E11:E126;"bolig")))
```

The latter formula has been working perfectly until now through my Work, but for this specific value i needed to remove the extra bracket.

Comment: I translated your functions to English, any solutions should also be provided in English :)

Comment: How large is the difference between the 2 results? And are the 2 versions of the formula in the same cell?

Comment: The real question is why are you summing the sum? P.S. without example it's to troublesome to decipher your formulas

Comment: Do Evaluate Formula (under the formulas tab) and step through each one to see where the different count is coming from.

Comment: I don't think extra brackets could change the meaning of the formula. Did you enter any of the as array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)? If you click on the cell and look at the formula bar, does it begin with '{'?

Answer (score 3):

Jacob is right that its the array bit that is causing the problem, but really the problem is caused by the + sign in an expression containing an array which causes the expression to be evaluated as an array formula. You can fix this by changing the + to ; (or whatever the argument separator character is in your locale).

A simpler example (my locale uses , rather than ;):

```
=SUM({5,10}+20)
```

results in 55 (the expression evaluater creates (5+20)+(10+20) using the array expansion rules and then passes {25,30} to SUM) but

```
=SUM({5,10},20)
```

results in 35

Comment: Good point, I glossed over this point completely. The SUM() function separates values based on "," or in this case ";". So within each value, it will recognize the array and return two values that get added.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.
I was not aware that the arrays were being read that way. I only used the arrays to be able to have more criteria for the sumifs.

Answer (score 0):

In your first SUMIFS() you have the criteria listed as an array. When using SUM() around the first SUMIFS() alone, it is returning the sum of the range that meets the first criteria being true in the range, then repeats for the second critera, and then it adds the second SUMIF().

When you add the parentheses, you SUM() the first SUMIF() total for the first array value AND the second SUMIF(), and then you are repeating for the second array. So you are getting that second SUMIF() total added twice essentially.

I believe you want something like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF('Ark1'!E15:E75;"adgangsareal bolig";'Ark1'!F15:F75);SUMIF('Ark1'!E15:E75;'Ark1'!F15:F75;"fællesrum bolig");SUMIF('Ark2'!E11:E126;"bolig";'Ark2'!F11:F126))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=(87,35+464,71-87,35-464,71)
=87,35+464,71-87,35-464,71
```

2nd formula results correctly in `ZERO`, while 
1st one results in very small number(`-0,0000000000000568434`)

Add more decimal places to see it.
I think it is a BUG and has something to do with different type of numbers (decimal, floating,...).